# HP Omen BSOD when disconnected from power

Tags: windows-10, laptop, bsod

I recently bought a new laptop (HP Omen 15-ax280nd), which is awesome for everything except for one crippling issue: Whenever I disconnect the power brick (making it run on battery power) I get a BSOD within 5 minutes (the exact delay differs every time).

The BSOD error code is

> DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE

I already tried the following:

- Run Windows Update (everything is up-to date)
- Enrol the device in the Windows Insider programme (preview and slow rings)
- Use HP support assistant to update drivers
- Reset drivers to original
- Uninstall drivers
- Disable Windows from powering down devices when on battery power
- BIOS is up-to date

The issue happened on two separate laptops (both an identical model), both directly after installing Windows, and after installing all my usual programs.

It happens both on Windows 10 Home x64 and Windows 10 Pro x64. Both versions in nl_NL and en_US.

I also already contacted HP about the issue, they helped me run a hardware diagnostic and remoted in to check some software settings, they also suggest that I return the laptop.

This issue does not occur in safe mode or on a Linux live CD.

The store has offered for me to get a refund or exchange it for another laptop, but I really like this one so would prefer to resolve this issue instead.

**dump files**

- [First file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0yjq6__PgghRGlic0FiN3FySTA/view?usp=sharing), I get this whenever I unplug my laptop from the power adapter.
- [Second file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0yjq6__PgghcTRmTEFsRHV4Zk0/view?usp=sharing), My laptop apparently crashed in my bag on my way home.
- [Thid file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0yjq6__PgghTHp5aTNCT1VrejA/view?usp=sharing), I get this whenever I try to update the graphics driver, regardless of whether or not my laptop is plugged in.

Comment: Have you checked if a BIOS update it available?

Comment: @JamesP The first laptop I had was running a newer BIOS than HP offered (F.34 while their most recent was F.33).. The second one is running the most recent (F.33) BIOS.

Comment: share (OneDrive) the dmp file from **C:\windows\minidump\** so that I can debug the crash

Comment: have you uplaoded the dmp? otherwise I can't help you

Comment: @magicandre1981 Oops, sorry! I'll do that right now!

Comment: @magicandre1981 [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0yjq6__PgghRGlic0FiN3FySTA/view?usp=sharing) it is. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: ok, I posted what I saw from the dump.

Comment: I got the same error on my Omen. Thanks for your issue, looks like it is an HP-specific issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After contacting HP support for several days, they were able to resolve the issue by updating my BIOS to version F.35.

I'm not sure when this BIOS was released, since at the time of posting I cannot find it on their site. However, they sent me a link to their FTP server to download it.

ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp79001-79500/sp79340.exe

Comment: nice to hear that a new BIOS/UEFI fixed it :)

Comment: My case was the following. Laptop had F.34, I downloaded F.38 from hp.com and it fixed BSOD problem. Finally I'm able to unplug power cord without crashing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [dmp with Windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks), shows that the NVIDIA GPU driver for your Geforce GTX 1050 (`PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1C8D`) causes the issue.

```
4: kd> !podev ffffbe8c0b68b840
Device object is for:
  DriverObject 0b5ea390
Current Irp 00000000 RefCount 0 Type 00000023 AttachedDev ffffbe8c0b68b620 DevFlags 00001040
Device queue is not busy.
Device Object Extension: ffffbe8c0b68bf90:
PowerFlags: 00000040 =>SystemState=0 DeviceState=4
Dope: 00000000:
4: kd> !devstack ffffbe8c0b68b620
  !DevObj           !DrvObj            !DevExt           ObjectName
  ffffbe8c0f3b7030  \Driver\nvlddmkm   ffffbe8c0f3b7180  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffbe8c0f3b7000

> ffffbe8c0b68b620  \Driver\ACPI       ffffbe8c0adff4b0  
  ffffbe8c0b68b840  \Driver\pci        ffffbe8c0b68b990  Cannot read info offset from nt!ObpInfoMaskToOffset

!DevNode ffffbe8c0b68b310 :
  DeviceInst is "PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1C8D&SUBSYS_8259103C&REV_A1\4&7f79032&0&0008"
  ServiceName is "nvlddmkm"
4: kd> !irp ffffbe8c0f299010
Irp is active with 6 stacks 4 is current (= 0xffffbe8c0f2991b8)
 No Mdl: No System Buffer: Thread 00000000:  Irp stack trace.  
     cmd  flg cl Device   File     Completion-Context
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>[IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_SET_POWER(2)]
            0 e1 ffffbe8c0b68b840 00000000 fffff80d1c8ded40-ffff970106e19850 Success Error Cancel pending
           \Driver\pci  dxgkrnl!DpiFdoPowerCompletionRoutine
            Args: 00000000 00000001 00000001 00000000
 [IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_SET_POWER(2)]
            0 e1 ffffbe8c0f3b7030 00000000 fffff80368bada00-ffffbe8c122595d8 Success Error Cancel pending
           \Driver\nvlddmkm nt!PopRequestCompletion
            Args: 00000000 00000001 00000001 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-ffffbe8c122595d8    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
4: kd> lmvm nvlddmkm
Browse full module list
start             end                 module name
fffff80d`1e6c0000 fffff80d`1f4b4000   nvlddmkm T (no symbols)           
    Loaded symbol image file: nvlddmkm.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvhm.inf_amd64_7c553af4468727c1\nvlddmkm.sys
    Image name: nvlddmkm.sys
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Mon Feb  6 12:03:14 2017 (589857F2)
    CheckSum:         00DB4D2F
    ImageSize:        00DF4000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
```

Your driver is a month old. The 1050 was released only some time ago. So a newer driver may fix it. [Install the latest driver](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/115892/en-us) (as on 2017-03-09) and look what happens. OEMs like HP often provide older drivers, so try the driver from nVIDIA.

Comment: Thanks! I'm just getting ready for bed but I'll try out your solution tomorrow. I did update the nvidia driver before using the most recent version from their website and still had the issue. I may just need to disable the card until a newer driver is released?

Comment: Before trying this I put my laptop to sleep and went home, apparently it BSOD'd in my bag on the way home with bug check code 0x00000139 (bluescreenview doesn't show a string). When I got home I uninstalled my video card driver (using the uninstaller from Guru 3D) and then installed version 378.78 for notebook 1050 from the nvidia site. During installation I got a VIDEO_DXGKRNL_FATAL_ERROR BSOD and after that I was signed into a temporary user account because Windows "could not sign me in to your user account".. Logging in again shows no bug check string in bluescreenview. Just 0x00000113.

Comment: I'll add the dump files to my original post.

Comment: the 0x00000139 could be caused by Malwarebytes driver hooking into diskIO/registry access of lsass.exe. the VIDEO_DXGKRNL_FATAL_ERROR is caused by nVIDIA driver again. it is still related to power saving operations of the GPU. can you flash to the F34, the current one uses F.33. maybe the newer driver + 34 BIOS solves it

Comment: My previous laptop (I already returned it once and got a new one) had F.34, unfortunately that one also had this error. I'll see what happens when I uninstall Malwarebytes.

Comment: While re-installing the driver, I got the same DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE error again. However, this time when I rebooted I got a message saying that it was due to a thermal error and the laptop rebooted to prevent overheating. Furthermore, HP support escalated my issue and gathered all kinds of diagnostics on the laptop so maybe they'll get back to me with a solution. I'll try flashing F.34 soon.

Comment: does the F34 improves it or do you still see the same issue? can you use Speedfan or MSI Afterburner to control the fan of the GPU? For laptops that may not work, but give it a try to run fans at higher speed to lower the temperature.

Comment: I had the same issue on F34, which is why I returned the first laptop. I'll see if I can control the fans later today when I get home.

Comment: have you looked in HP forums? Is this an issue that other users also see? Maybe it is a design flow about the GPU in this HP laptop series.

Comment: Googling around for this issue didn't show me any other users experiencing the same issue unfortunately. Also, whenever I launch afterburner the computer immediately blue screens (DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE)

Comment: can you use speedfan to control the fans? http://www.almico.com/sfarticle.php?id=5

Comment: I can see all temps in speedfan except for GPU. Both fans show 0%. [screenshot](https://ducohosting.com/screenshots/lapec10b784787d52ed01bde5020bdcc576.png)

Comment: It seems that speedfan and afterburner intermittently do report a temperature and fan speed (about once a minute). If they do report it, the driver temp hovers around 35C.

Comment: I have no real idea. phone HP support again

Comment: Thanks for trying though :) I managed to get the issue escalated so hopefully they'll come up with a fix soon.

Comment: In the end HP support helped me resolve it by installing BIOS version F.35.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem after a windows update.

I tried updating all of my drivers via HP assist, and uninstalling/reinstalling my wifi and GPU drivers using the Drivers provided on HP's website but to no avail.

I finally fixed it by uninstalling NVIDIA GPU drivers and reinstalling directly from NVIDIA.
However, after installing the drivers from NVIDIA you must update the drivers through their GeForce experience application.
(Open GeForce Experience (you may need to create an account) -> Drivers tab -> Check For Updates -> Clean Install -> reboot)
It seems like HP hosts the stock drivers on their website, rather than the latest drivers from the manufacturer.

Hope this helps!
I am running BIOS F.34 btw.

Comment: Thanks! So basically I should download the latest drivers from the NVIDIA site and then update to the latest(?) drivers using GeForce Experience?

Comment: Whenever I install the latest driver from nvidia.com and restart the laptop I immediately get a VIDEO_DXGKRNL_FATAL_ERROR BSOD. (If I don't first get the DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE BSOD while installing the driver)

Comment: Even after fixing that issue, I'm afraid that your solution doesn't help me :(

Comment: Are you doing this while running on battery power or while plugged in?

Comment: I tried both running it on the battery and when plugged in.