# Driver Update Failure Leading to BSOD in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, bsod, nvidia-graphics-card

I am running into an issue on my laptop where I am getting a `Blue Screen of Death` (`BSOD`) when running games or using the internet; the games I am running are online games. My laptop is an `MSI GL72 7RD` running `Windows 10`, 1607. It has an `Nvidia 1050 graphics card` in it and I attempted to update the driver and it failed this morning; it seems since then I am having these issues. There was also an update I ran for Nahimic 2 which I believe is Audio related. I have received BSOD errors with `DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE` listed in it; I had received another early on but now it appears to be principly the `DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE` message. The system runs fine if I am not running games or on the internet. I have read some online this is a network related issue; such as a network related driver issue. I have gotten the drivers from NVidia and MSI for this machine/hardware; tried to run the WLAN driver install and the NVIDIA driver (current and past driver) and they all fail at this point with a BSOD. There is no Restore Point as that was not enabled by default; although it is now and I have created a base restore point as I try to trouble shoot. I had read that possible the Power Settings could be to blame and I reset them to the defaults to no avail. I have checked the Event Viewer and nothing stands out; I do see error messages related to the start up after the crash but nothing preceding it. I ran a virus scan (Quick Scan) and found nothing. I checked the hard drives for errors, C is an SSD and D is a standard HDD, and there were no errors reported.

Here is an updated snipped of the minidump files:
[image]

I see many many many articles related to BSOD but as this is such a general error it is hard to navigate; any pointers are great appreciated on trouble shooting this. Thanks to everyone who reads.

Comment: Are you running 1607 or 1703?

Comment: Thank you for replying; can you clarify what you are referring to and I will check? Is this the OS version et al.?

Comment: 1607 and 1703 are featured updates.  1607 is the current feature update while 1703 is being released on April 11 but you can manually install it today

Comment: I'll check the OS updates...

Comment: Open RUN and type "WINVER" and press OK. The Version and Build entry are what we need to see.

Comment: Sorry; was on the road. Ok, the version is 1607 (OS Build 14393.969).

Comment: Its 1607; Ramhound do you think I should install 1703 and how should I do that?

Comment: share all dmp files from **C:\Windows\minidump**

Comment: I've got the files; there are 3; how can I view them/read them?

Comment: I used a utility to open and read the files; I took a screen shot and attached it to the description above. Let me know if I need to provide more detail.

Comment: I need the actual file,s not this bluescreenviewer bullshit, Zip the 3 files into 1 zip and upload the zip (onedrive) and post the share link here. also notifiy my with @my username

Comment: @magicandre1981, I have uploaded an archive will several dumps including one from today here:
http://www.mediafire.com/file/ucbtxtgkl1o72d7/MiniDumpArchive.zip

Comment: ok, I posted an answer from what I saw from the dumps

Comment: any update? have you applied the latest BIOS/UEFI?

Answer (score 0):

[By looking at the dump with Windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) I see that it could be could by the nVIDIA GPU driver

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffcd045fb05840, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: fffff803b55de8e0, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffcd0464815bd0, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------
STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KiSwapContext
01 nt!KiSwapThread
02 nt!KiCommitThreadWait
03 nt!KeWaitForSingleObject
04 ACPI!SyncEvalObject
05 ACPI!AMLIEvalNameSpaceObject
06 ACPI!ACPIIoctlEvalControlMethod
07 ACPI!ACPIIrpDispatchDeviceControl
08 ACPI!ACPIDispatchIrp
09 dxgkrnl!DpiDispatchIoctl
0a nvlddmkm
0b 0x0
0c 0x0
0d 0x0
0e 0x0
0f 0x0
10 0x0
11 0x0
12 nvlddmkm
13 0x0
14 0x0
15 0x0
16 nvlddmkm
17 0x0
18 nvlddmkm
19 0x0
1a 0x0
1b 0x0
1c 0x0
1d 0x0
1e 0x0
1f 0x0
20 0x0
21 0x0
22 nt!IoGetAttachedDeviceReference
23 nvlddmkm
24 0x0
25 0x0
26 0x0
27 0x0

0: kd> !podev ffffcd045fb05840
Device object is for:
  DriverObject 5fb4ec60
Current Irp 00000000 RefCount 0 Type 00000023 AttachedDev ffffcd045fb0d880 DevFlags 00001040
Device queue is not busy.
Device Object Extension: ffffcd045fb05f90:
PowerFlags: 00000010 =>SystemState=0 DeviceState=1
Dope: 00000000:
0: kd> !devstack ffffcd045fb0d880
  !DevObj           !DrvObj            !DevExt           ObjectName
  ffffcd0463c76030  \Driver\nvlddmkm   ffffcd0463c76180  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffcd0463c76000

> ffffcd045fb0d880  \Driver\ACPI       ffffcd045e0a68b0  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffcd045fb0d850

  ffffcd045fb05840  \Driver\pci        ffffcd045fb05990  Cannot read info offset from nt!ObpInfoMaskToOffset

!DevNode ffffcd045fb05510 :
  DeviceInst is "PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1C8D&SUBSYS_11C91462&REV_A1\4&c37bf5&0&0008"
  ServiceName is "nvlddmkm"
```

[I saw the same issue some time ago](https://superuser.com/a/1187066/174557). This user also uses a Geforce GTX 1050 and here the user contacted HP to get a new BIOS. Because you use a MSI GL72 7RD, get the latest BIOS/UEFI, because your `BIOS Version E1799IMS.309` is a bit old. Apply the last [version E1799IMS.312](https://msi.com/Laptop/support/GL72-7RD.html#down-bios) and look if it fixes the issue.